# Class property not defined

Tags: python, loops

```
a = input("Enter synaptic input strength: ")
infile = [a]
i = 0
elements = []

class Neuron:
    def __init__(self, f, inputN):
        self.f = f
        self.inputN = inputN
    
    isNeuron = "true" 
    def inpadd(self, inp):
        elements = []
        elements.append(inp)
        for element in range(len(inputN)):
            elements.append(element)
            elements.append(element)

N1 = Neuron("Sum", infile)
Nlist = []
Nlist.append(N1)
for item in range(len(Nlist)):
    for element in range(len(infile)):
         name = Nlist[i]
         name.inpadd(infile[i])
         print(item.elements)
         i = i + 1
```

I'm attempting to create the start of a program that will simulate a collection of neurons. I have a class property elements[] which I append the input to before eventually processing it in a master function which modifies the inputs (summing them, multiplying them) based on the type of Neuron. Unfortunately, every time I run the program I get the error message

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 25, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 15, in inpadd
  NameError: name 'inputN' is not defined
```

Which inplies that the inputN variable is not defined. Is there something wrong with the scope of the variables or does the problem lie elsewhere?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need `self.inputN` to refer to a member variable.

Comment: You have two entirely different things named `inputN` here: a parameter to the `__init__` method (which does not exist outside of that method), and an instance attribute (that you'd have to prefix with `self.` for reading, just as you did when assigning to it).

Comment: And you're just appending the INDEXES of the values.  `elements` (which should probably be `self.elements`) will end up being [0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3..].  You probably wanted `for element in self.inputN:`.

Comment: in Python you have to use `self.` to acces class variables. In some other languages you could skip `self.` (or similar element) and it would work.